# Flutter image not displaying: "Unable to load asset"

Tags: flutter

Instead of seeing my image in my app I'm seeing a red box with an X that says `Unable to load asset: images/aboutmaggie.png.`

I made a directory `assets` with a subdirectory `images`. The directory `assets` is at the same level as `pubspec.yaml`.

I put the image into the `images` directory. When I click on the image in Android Studio the image displays.

[image]

In `pubspec.yaml` I have these lines:

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

I added

```java
class AboutRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const AboutRoute({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Kabbalistic Numerology'),
        ),
        body: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            children: <Widget>[
              RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(
                        text: 'About Maggie McPherson',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(
                        text:
                            "Dr. Leslie Margaret Perrin McPherson...",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Image.asset('images/aboutmaggie.png'), // <--this image doesn't load
            ]));
  }
}
```

I ran `flutter pub get`. I ran Tools > Flutter > Flutter Clean. I shut down and restarted Android Studio.

The error message is:

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: images/aboutmaggie.png
```

I tried putting another image into `assets/images` and calling that but the second image wouldn't load either.

What's wrong with this picture?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**there is an error in calling the image,**

change this line in your code

```
Image.asset('images/aboutmaggie.png')
```

to this line

```
Image.asset('assets/images/aboutmaggie.png')
```

I hope this helps, thankyou

Comment: I tried that last night and it didn't work. I tried it this morning and it worked. Is Flutter (or the iOS emulator) cacheing pubspec.yaml?

Answer (score 3):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.

Refer documation [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images) for **Adding assets and images**

Refer Image Class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html)

**Your folder structure**

```
project directory
   - assets
       - images
          - your_image.png
```

**Your `pubspec.yaml` file**

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

**Your Widget:**

```
   Image.asset(
        'assets/images/ln.png',//just change your image to my image
        height: 150,
        //width: 100,
      ),
```

***Note*** - If you adding correct code and details then your problem not resolved then stop(exit) the project/app and relaunch again

Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: I tried that last night and it didn't work. I tried it this morning and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
Image.asset('assets/images/aboutmaggie.png'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide complete path of the image.
Replace
`Image.asset('images/aboutmaggie.png')`
with
`Image.asset('assets/images/aboutmaggie.png')`.

Answer (score 0):

It was cacheing issue. Last night I tried

```java
Image.asset('assets/images/aboutmaggie.png'),
```

but that didn't work. This morning I started up Android Studio and it asked,

```
pubspec.yaml has changed. Do you want to run flutter pub get?
```

Well, that's odd. I'd just started Android Studio. I hadn't changed anything. I changed the path back to `'assets/images/aboutmaggie.png'`, ran `flutter pub get`, did a hot restart and the image appeared.

Then I opened `pubspec.yaml` and changed it to

```java
  assets:
    - assets/bowlingballs/
```

I ran `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, did another hot restart, and the image continued to appear.

I changed the path back to `'images/aboutmaggie.png'`, ran `flutter pub get`, did a hot restart and the image was gone.

My conclusion is that if you change this path

```java
Image.asset('assets/images/aboutmaggie.png'),
```

then run `flutter pub get` and a hot restart then the change will appear. But if you make changes to `pubspec.yaml` you won't see changes until some cache is cleared. The problem I had last night was that when I set up `pubspec.yaml` I had an extra space before `assets`. That version of `pubspec.yaml` got cached and subsequent versions of `pubspec.yaml` were ignored. `flutter clean` clears the Build cache but `pubspec.yaml` apparently isn't in the Build cache. `pubspec.yaml` must be cached somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal, run **flutter clean** to clear up the cache, then run **flutter pub get** for flutter to fetch your assets folder afresh

This is what worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error, tried everything for 2 days and nothing worked.

What worked was:

- **manually delete the build folder from your directory**

After that run on your terminal

```
flutter clean
```

`flutter run`
(this will build the build folder again)

(run `flutter build` if the flutter run command doesn't work)

This may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation of assets: in pubspec.yaml is very important . Ensure that assets: is properly indented